# Weird MySQL error

Tags: php, mysql

The following piece of code gets a page via `curl`, extracts some strings from it and **should** update some MySQL columns.

My problem is that for the following code I'm an error (see under `output` below).

When I copy/paste the query and place it in the SQL editor in phpmyadmin, it works perfectly. Also, if I replace the parameters `$price` and `$stockid` in my code with the actual numbers that are listed in the output, it also works. How is that even possible?

If feel like I'm missing something really stupid.

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT STOCK_TRADE_NAME,STOCK_ID FROM current_stocks WHERE STOCK_COUNTRY_ID = 7 LIMIT 1,9");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {
    $stockid = $row['STOCK_ID'];
    $url = "http://www.some.url.com/?stock_name=" . $row['STOCK_TRADE_NAME'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $dom = new simple_html_dom;
    $dom->load($output);
    foreach($dom->find('span.amount') as $e) {
        $price = str_replace(',','',$e->outertext);
    }
    foreach($dom->find('tr.even') as $f) {
        if (strstr($f->outertext,'<td class="name">Open</td>')) {
            $exp = explode('<td class="value">',$f->outertext);
            $open = str_replace('</td>','',$exp[1]);
        }
    }
    echo $stockid . " " . $price . "<br>";
    mysql_query("UPDATE current_stocks SET STOCK_CURRENT_PRICE = $price WHERE STOCK_ID = $stockid") or die(mysql_error());
    $ch="";  
    $dom="";

}
```

**Output**:

```
345 11.300
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '11.300 WHERE STOCK_ID = 345' at line 1
```

Note: STOCK_ID is INT(11), STOCK_CURRENT_PRICE is DECIMAL(8,3)

Note2: I'm using the latest MySQL/PhpMyAdmin/PHP version.

**UPDATE**:

Editing the query to this:

```
$q2 = "UPDATE current_stocks SET STOCK_CURRENT_PRICE = '" . $price . "' WHERE STOCK_ID = '" . $stockid . "'";
mysql_query($q2) or die(mysql_error());
```

Removes the error message, but does not update the db.

Comment: have you tried WHERE STOCK_ID = . "\'" . $price . "\'"

Comment: What if you put the query in a variable first and output that query. Does that query run fine in phpMyAdmin? It seems everything is okay, unless MySQL wouldn't accept the `.` in the price...

Comment: Please post the results of `var_dump($q2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If adding quotes doesn't change anything, check for whitespace characters — maybe even inside `$price`. Is there a hidden tab or return that is not visible in html?

Try something like `$price = preg_replace("/'\s+'", '', $price);` (not tested).

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating `$price` in quotes: `'$price'`;

Answer (score 0):

quick fix: adding `''` to your query:

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE current_stocks SET STOCK_CURRENT_PRICE = '$price' WHERE STOCK_ID = '$stockid'") or die(mysql_error());
```

better: use a parametrized query so your content and logic are separated: you won't have this problem, and get a fix for possible injections free of charge :)

Comment: What is the content of your database beforehand, what is the exact query, and what is the content afterwards? It seems like your conclusion that nothings happens (while there should) is wrong: the query gets executed if there is no error here, or theres a problem somewehre else.

Answer (score -2):

I think this line of code is the issue:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE current_stocks SET STOCK_CURRENT_PRICE = $price WHERE STOCK_ID = $stockid")
```

You can't reference php variables in mysql queries, but rather should use a sprintf command to create a text string which is then passed to your mysql database.

So your query should be:

```
$query = sprintf("Update current_stocks set stock_current_price = '%s' where stock_id = '%s'", $price, $stockid);
```

then create your mysql query reference:

```
mysql_query($query);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: *You can't reference php variables in mysql queries*. Why would you say that? What happens is that php parses every `$var` in a string enclosed with `"`, so you can actually do this. If you look at the error, you see that the contents of those strings are actually pushed to mysql, but the query is invalid.

Comment: "You can't reference php variables in mysql queries" Are you sure??

Comment: Or W didn't originally have the variable broken out of the ", so it was just being read as a text string.  Looks like he broke out the variable when he updated his question (or you can do what I did above).